# Storing large blob with Objectify Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have this class which I want to persist using Objectify, this class will represent a data larger than 1MB so there's a List of Blob objects which represents a fragment of the byte array stored that is less than 1MB in size:

```
@Entity
public class BigBlob {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_LIMIT = 777 * 1024;
    @Serialized
    private List<Blob> fragments = new ArrayList<Blob>();

    ...

}
```

Yet, the the "fragments" is @Serialized, which will render the size of this BigBlob class/object larger than 1MB.

Causing this error:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
```

If I use @Embedded annotation I get this error:

```
Cannot place array or collection properties inside @Embedded arrays or collections
```

How do I make sure that the "fragments" are stored as a separate entity?

BTW, I already have the byte chunking logic that chops the whole byte array and put the fragments into a `List` of `Blob` so this question does not pertain as to how to chop bytes.

Mostly what I want to know is more on the persisting side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rick's answer is really the best - store blobs in the blobstore, especially if you are new to GAE and having conceptual issues with the datastore.

On the other hand, there are some good reasons to use split entities for storing blobs, especially if you are storing data that is close to the 1M edge.  You wouldn't want to do this with 100MB blobs, but 2MB blobs can make sense.

First of all, you don't want serialized or embedded.  Those are simply ways to structure data inside a single entity.

Also, there's no magic annotation that lets you split blobs across entities.  You have to do it all by hand.  You don't need to actually create a 'master' or root entity; just create all the entity fragments with a parent defined by an id (but no actual entity) and use an ancestor() query to fetch all the pieces.

Comment: "On the other hand, there are some good reasons to use split entities for storing blobs, especially if you are storing data that is close to the 1M edge" - not really, there's no reason you can't store blobs smaller than 1MB in the blobstore, too.

Comment: You certainly can, but the blobstore-related APIs are a pain to work with and cannot easily be made transactional with other datastore work.  Sometimes it's considerably easier to use the datastore, even with the multiple-entity hack.  On the other hand, blobstore storage is cheaper than datastore storage, so this choice should not be made frivolously.

Comment: What about the blobstore APIs is hard to work with? And why do you need a transaction that spans the blobstore and the datastore?

Comment: Compared to the simplicity of put()ing or get()ing an entity, the Files API is a monstrosity, and using the normal blob upload URL is highly invasive to program logic.  Regarding transactions - why *wouldn't* you want transactions that span blobstore and datastore?  I often write a blob and some additional metadata for that blob.  I have to go through some significant hoops to make the operation should be transactional-ish.

Comment: I don't know why it qualifies as a 'monstrosity' - it's as simple as it can be to achieve what it needs to do, in my opinion. And the comparison isn't to a single put - it's to whatever infrastructure you need to build to span a blob property across multiple entities!

Comment: @stickfigure You mean, the FileService API actually uploading files when I write a AppengineFile? In my case I did store metadata with Objectify and store using the bytes using Fileservice api

Comment: With all the files and channels and locks and readers and writers, the Java Files API feels overengineered.  The Python Files API does not appear to suffer the same problem, and this isn't explained by language differences.  While you still need some boilerplate to do multi-entity blobs, it's a trivial amount and intuitive to someone already familiar with the datastore API.  But really, the main argument for multi-entity blobs is being able to integrate with the transactional logic of your application.

Comment: The Google Storage is slow with bulk operations (e.g. archive) if you have many (millions) small blobs. Then is may be better to use DataStore and split blobs which exceed 1MB.

Comment: There is still limit 10MB per query, so if you split more than 10MB file then you cannot get it by one query.

Answer (score 4):

You should store it in the Blobstore and just save the Blobkey in Objectify. Objectify works on top of the datastore, not the blobstore.